# Force Crystal Reports to run in an x86 build?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, x86, 64-bit

Here's the situation:

I'm currently working on a substantially large .Net application that makes use of Crystal Reports, as well as a few other 32-bit libraries (to do with things like signature pads).  We are currently using an older version of Crystal Reports (in Visual Studio 2005.. I know, it's old.  They will eventually upgrade).  We currently do separate builds for 32-bit machines and for 64-bit machines.  The build for 32-bit machines are target the AnyCPU platform while the build for 64-bit machines target the x86 platform.  This is done so that when the application runs on a 64-bit machine the app will run as a 32-bit app and still be able to load the other 32-bit libraries.

I'm getting quite tired of having to maintain two separate builds (the build process is a bit of a mess as it is).  My thought is that I'd like to only do a build that targets the x86 platform, as then everything would still continue to work, but it would save having to maintain separate builds for 32-bit and 64-bit machines.

My question is this: Is it possible to force a 32-bit install of Crystal Reports on a 64-bit machine?  Will an application that is built for the x86 platform continue to work against a 32 bit version of Crystal Reports on a 64-bit machine?

Is what I am looking to do possible, or am I missing something else?  I feel like I'm missing - as though the previous developers didn't do this for some obvious reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "64-bit" build is set to x86 (32-bit) and your "32-bit" build only runs in x86 (32-bit) because there is no 64-bit, the builds are basically identical and there's no need for two builds.  I build my Crystal Reports app as x86, and pre-install the 32-bit Crystal msi.  It works like a champ on both 64-bit and 32-bit machines.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking as well - that there really isn't any difference to the end user between builds - they are either running as a 32 bit build on a 32 bit machine or running as a 32 bit build on a 64 bit machine.  Did you have any issues getting a 32 bit version of Crystal Reports to install on a 64 bit machine?  I thought the installer could be quite picky about stuff like that.

Comment: I didn't.  Sometimes I've gone as far as launching a "32-bit console" (c:\windows\syswow64\cmd.exe), but other users have just r-clicked and "run as administrator" successfully.